# Alfresco - How to make admin unable to delete user from Active Directory

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, administration

Is there a way to make admin not able to delete user from Active Directory? I need to disable this feature some how in global properies or else. I want admin only to create users,edit them and disable them, but not delete. The version of Alfresco is Community 5.2. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you setup the sync with active directory?

Comment: It wasn't me, i am on project where someone already did the setup , i now have to change it somehow, first time doing it and dont have any idead how to do this, the information on the documentation is not much. @Gagravarr

Comment: Does Alfresco synchronize users from Active Directory (AD) automatically? With sync deleted users in Alfresco, but existing in AD will recreated. If you setted option `synchronization.allowDeletions=false` in `alfresco-global.properies` sync job will NOT be allowed to delete users in Alfresco deleted in AD. But this only applies to sync settings.

Comment: I have already did this, but as you said this only applies to sync settings. Is there a way to  disable admin to delete users? What i did is just hide the button using css, but i think that this approach is not good. Any ideas? @AlekseyB.

Comment: @john2994 I'm in agreeement that there are not supported ways to restrict admin permission

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you mean the other way around:

> Is there a way to prevent admin from deleting users which have been created by ldap sync?

or do you mean:

> Is there a way to revoke permission to delete any user?

Do you understand the difference between a user which has been created by ldap sync and a user manually created in the Alfresco admin UI?

There is no (easy and supported) way I know of to restrict admin permissions or for a member of the group ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS. The ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR has always any permission.

There maybe a way to achieve what you expect in a customization module implementing a new behavior which disallows user deletion in a specific zone or by creating your own permissionGroups/permissions in a [customPermissionDefinitions](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/dev-extensions-modules-custom-permission-model.html), setting the new introduced permissions on the user zones to specific groups but that kind of customization would be hard to maintain on later updates/upgrades.

EDIT:
What is your use case for allowing (end) users to create new users inside Alfresco although you have an user directory (AD) in place?

If your aim is to support external users, managed by specific internal user groups you may add another directory like samba4 which your internal users may get permissions to create/delete users (that's what we actually do from/thru our CRM system) or if you prefer integrations with OAuth2 providers such as Google, Facebook, Github you may take a look on the [Spring Cloud Gateway for the Alfresco platform](https://github.com/dgradecak/alfresco-jwt-auth) project